# Discrete mathematics Relations Question

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, relations

if r2 is in the set of N*N ( natural numbers) with (X,y) in the subset of r2, if and only if x+y=0

is it reflexive? 
is it symmetric?
is it anti symmetric?
is it Transitive?

i said it is reflective because 0+0 =0

but i'm a little stuck beyond that. the only relation in the set would be (0,0) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you have a relation $R_2\subseteq\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ defined by $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$ if and only if $x+y=0$. If this is correct, then $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is the only element of $R_2$, but that does not make $R_2$ reflexive: in order for $R_2$ to be reflexive, $\langle n,n\rangle$ would have to be in $R_2$ for **every** $n\in\Bbb N$, which is clearly not the case. For instance, $\langle 1,1\rangle\notin R_2$, even though $1\in\Bbb N$. Thus, $R_2$ is **not** reflexive. $R_2$ is both symmetric and transitive, however,

- **Symmetry:** Is it true that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$, then $\langle y,x\rangle\in R_2$ as well? Yes: if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$, then $x=y=0$, so $\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle\in R_2$.
- **Transitivity:** Is it true that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$ and $\langle y,z\rangle\in R_2$, then $\langle x,z\rangle\in R_2$? The answer is again *yes*, and the proof is similar; can you complete it?

Comment: suppose (x,y) and (y,z) then (x,z) exists in the set R2?

Comment: @user2813423: I’m not sure what you mean. In order to show that $R_2$ is transitive, you must show that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$ and $\langle y,z\rangle\in R_2$, then $\langle x,z\rangle\in R_2$. In this case you know that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_2$ and $\langle y,z\rangle\in R_2$, then $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle=\langle y,z\rangle$, so ... ?

Comment: so (x,y)=(y,z)=(x,z) +(0,0) ∈ R2

Comment: @user2813423: Yes, assuming that the plus sign was supposed to be an equals sign. And therefore $R_2$ is transitive.

Comment: haha yes that was supposed to be an equal sign, sorry. thanks for clarifying everything, my professor did a horrible job explaining

Comment: @user2813423: You’re welcome.